# Mysql Query for unique slugs

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have made a wordpress plugin to find and replace keywords in database, where admin provides keywords to find and to replace, and then the MYSQL query does the changes in DB.
But all I want to know the way to avoid the duplicate slugs.
For example :
As if there are two posts with following slugs:

1. firstpost
2. secondpost

and then admin runs the query and wants to replace "second" with "first".
then the result will be:

```
update wp_posts set `post_name` = replace(post_name, 'second','first') where post_type='post'
```

1. firstpost
2. firstpost

Is there a way to keep the slugs unique ?

Comment: By far the simplest solution will be adding a [unique constraint to the database column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/constraint-primary-key.html) and catching the error thrown if a duplicate is found.

Comment: As an addition to @sjdaws :When there is a duplicate entry for a unique constraint, you will get a specific error code, if i remember correctly `1062`. Put the query inside a `try-catch` block and inside the catch you can then check if the error code equals 1062.

Comment: This is a messy solution in my opinion, and it doesn't really achieve what's been requested - which is to find a way to enable both the keyword swap and preserve uniqueness in the slugs. See my solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This update query works with a derived table to check if the change would create a duplicate slug. If it would, a number is appended to the existing slug for the would-be duplicate.

```
UPDATE 
  wp_posts p, 

  (SELECT 
     REPLACE(post_name,'second', 'first') AS post_name 
   , COUNT(post_name) AS num_dupes 
   FROM 
     wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'post' 
   GROUP BY 
     REPLACE(post_name, 'second', 'first')) d

SET p.post_name = CONCAT(REPLACE(p.post_name, 'second', 'first'), 
         CASE WHEN num_dupes > 1 THEN num_dupes - 1 ELSE '' END)

WHERE
  p.post_type='post' AND 
  p.post_name = d.post_name
```

In my opinion this is a better solution than using a unique constraint on the post_name field because a) you don't need to make custom DML changes to the wordpress database and b) you prevent the issue of a duplicate occurring, and of having to handle the error, before it happens.

Comment: Thanks @Simon for you answer. Working exactly what I was looking for.